# Is it reasonable to use the output of the sigmoid function as the win rate prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, sigmoid

I'm working on a project which is predicting the win rate of one team or one person.(could be any kind of sports like baseball, basketball or e-sport games)
The data I have is more like a classification problem. Data looks like this, A v.s B, the winner is A. So, I trained a classification model with those data. The model should input two units(a team or a person) and output a probability from sigmoid, so I should set a threshold to determine the output is  1 or 0.
But I'm curious about if the output of the sigmoid can be considered as the win rate? I think the answer might be yes? But I got next question.
My goal is to predict the win rate of one unit(team or person), which means I don't care about opponents. So When using this model to predict, for example, I want to predict Lakers win rate, and I make the match-up with all the others teams(29 teams) as the opponents, and make the 29 pieces data like Laker vs Hawks, Laker vs Mavericks,...and so on, then I got the 29 output from sigmoid. Here are two choices I have. First,  setting the threshold for the output of sigmoid and determine the result is 1 or 0. Then calculate the win rate
Or I can just get the mean of all the 29 games' output from sigmoid(no threshold setting).

I think the first one is more reasonable, but second one is outperform first one in my experiment. So, does the second one make any sense?
I'm not fluent in English. Please bear with me

Comment: For this kind of problems you probably can get more responses on https://datascience.stackexchange.com or https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just on initial though, I think that makes sense. The probability is giving you how likely the Lakers would win. So it would make sense the probabilities would outperform the simple "1" or "0". There's a difference between saying the Lakers have 50.0001% chance to win and a 100% chance to win in terms of a win rate. Both would indicate "1" in that scenario, but obviously there's a big range between those probabilities. So sure, using the probability of winning as a win rate makes sense to me.